# Can a honours supervisors be called a Project Leader?

Tags: ethics, advisor

I am completing my undergraduate honours.
To do some of my experiments I am considering applying for some supercomputer time.
I would be applying to a external organistation who manages supercomputer for research in this state.
It funded by a partnership of universities (including my own) and the state and national government.

One of the conditions on the application is that the listed "**Project Leader**" be a non-student member of a university.
Can I (after talking to my supervisor), fill out the paperwork, listing him as "**Project Leader**"?
Even if his (direct) contributions are minimal, I would still be going to him for advice regularly, so he would be providing leadership on the project.

On the other hand, I would be the person doing all the interactions with the people from the supercomputing organisation.

Comment: I assume you have asked your supervisor about that? You certainly cannot book supercomputer time on his name without asking him first, right?

Comment: I explictly said "After speaking to him." in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a fairly standard description of a supervisors role in undergraduate research projects. Typically supervisor, despite potentially limited input, are responsible for the research conduct of their students. This might include booking of resources (e.g., labs or super computer time) and ethical approval for research that involves human and animal testing.